# Angular 2 --alpha 37 How to get properties in constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my component and its property is type

```
   @Component({
    selector: 'canvasContainer',
    properties: ['type']
    })
    @View({
    templateUrl: "components/canvas/canvas.html",
    directives: [Bar, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
    styleUrls: ['app.css']
    })
   export class Canvas 
    {
    constructor() {    }
    }
```

This is my html page:

```
<bar type="pie"></bar>
```

I want to get type pie in my constructor like this:

```
@Component({
        selector: 'canvasContainer',
        properties: ['type']
        })
        @View({
        templateUrl: "components/canvas/canvas.html",
        directives: [Bar, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
        styleUrls: ['app.css']
        })
       export class Canvas 
        {
        constructor() { alert(type);   }//this alert is not working
        }
```

Comment: I was looking for styleUrls example, so landed here, and added the styleUrls: ['app.css'] in my component and created a app.css too. But I think it is not included, Am I missing to include any component for this, can you please post a plunkr demo if possible

Comment: @RAVIMONE Have you included <link href="path to app.css"> in your index.html

Comment: do I need to include it, If so, then what is the point in using styleUrls:[], If I include it directly in index.html file, it will anyways applies to whole app?

Comment: yeah you are right...actualy you have to include the whole path of the styleSheet in the styleUrls for example : " styleUrls: ['path] ". its working fine for me. try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "@attribute" to get your value in the constructor.

1. `import {Component, View,CORE_DIRECTIVES,Attribute} from 'angular2/angular2';`

2.replace your constructor with following code.

```
 constructor(@Attribute('type') type:string) { alert(type);   }
```

Done.

Comment: Note the string you pass to the `@Attribute` decorator is the HTML version e.g. if your property was `sort-by` in javascript it is usually in camelCase (`sortBy`) where as the html looks like: `<div [sort-by]="key">`. So you have to use `@Attribute('sort-by')`.